# Validation Are Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

When I run these code following Snippet in img Errors

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   homeApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
>   module ngStorage due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngStorage'
>   is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to
>   load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

Are raise And Validation is not Working...

```js
var homeApp= angular.module("homeApp",['ngStorage']);
 

homeApp.controller("homeController",function($scop,$localStorage){
 
 $scop.saveData=function(){
  var leads = document.homeForm.leads.value;
     var email = document.homeForm.email.value;
     var phone = document.homeForm.phone.value;   
     var referance = document.homeForm.referance.value;
     var nameref = document.homeForm.nameref.value;
     var preftime = document.homeForm.preftime.value;

       
  var myObj={"leads":leads , "email":email, 
                 "phone":phone, "referance":referance, 
                 "nameref":nameref, "preftime":preftime}
                 $localStorage.myObj=myObj;
             }

});
homeApp.controller('AppController', [function() {
                    var self = this;
                    self.submit = function() {
                        console.log('Form is submitted with following user', self.user);
                    };
                }]
                );
```

```css
 .color {
            color: red;
            font-size:small;
        }

        input.ng-touched,select.ng-touched,input.ng-invalid{
           border: 2px solid red;
        }
        input.ng-valid,select.ng-valid{
            border: 1px solid #99ff33;            
        }
        input.ng-untouched,select.ng-untouched,checkbox{
             border: 1px transparent;
        }
        #left{
         width: 50%;
         float: left;
         
        }
        #right{
   width: 50%;
         float: right;
         
        }
        .header{
         text-align: center;
         font-size: 80px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .bt{
         float: left;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Leads</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validation.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ngStorage-master/ngStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js">    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js'></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<!--Mask Input For Contect Number-->
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#phone").mask("9999-999-999");
        });
</script>
<!--/Mask Input For Contect Number-->

<!--Insert In Locale Storage-->
<script type="text/javascript">

function check()
{
    var leads = document.homeForm.leads.value;
    var email = document.homeForm.email.value;
    var phone = document.homeForm.phone.value;   
    var referance = document.homeForm.referance.value;
    var nameref = document.homeForm.nameref.value;
    var preftime = document.homeForm.preftime.value;

    

    var data = [{"leads":leads , "email":email, 
                 "phone":phone, "referance":referance, 
                 "nameref":nameref, "preftime":preftime}];
    var store= JSON.stringify(data);
    var d = localStorage.setItem('Leads',store);
}
</script>
<!--/Insert In Locale Storage-->

    
</head>




<body ng-app="homeApp" ng-controller="homeController"  >
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header">Add Leads</div>
        <br><br>
  <form class="form-group" name="homeForm">
   <div >
                <!-- left Panel-->
    <div id="left" class="container">
     <label>Leads Name</label>
      <input type="text" 
         id="leads" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  name="leads"
                  ng-model="leads" 
                        tabindex="1"
                  placeholder="Enter Lead Name" 
                  required
                  />
                        <span ng-show="homeForm.leads.$touched && homeForm.leads.$error.required"><div class="color">Enter Name</div></span>
          <!--<span ng-show="homeForm.leads.$error.required"><div class="color">Lead Name is Required!!!</div></span>--><br>
     <label>Contect No</label>
          <input type="text" 
         id="" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  name="phone"
                  ng-model="phone" 
                  placeholder="Enter Phone Number" 
                        ng-minlength="10"
                        mask="####-###-###" 
                        ng-maxlength="12"
                        tabindex="3"
                  required
                  />
                        <span ng-show="homeForm.phone.$touched && homeForm.phone.$error.required"><div class="color">Enter Contect Number</div></span>
      <br>
                    <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" 
                                        ng-model="maycontect" 
                                        name="maycontect"
                                        id="maycontect"
                                        value="" 
                                        tabindex="6">May Contet</label>
            </div>

       <div  class="radio"  ng-show="maycontect">
       <label class="container"><b>Preffered Time:</b>
                                    <div>
                                        <span >
                                        <input type="radio" name="preftime" ng-model="preftime"> Morning &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <input type="radio" name="preftime"  ng-model="preftime"> Afternoon &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <input type="radio" name="preftime"  ng-model="preftime"> Evening &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
          
                                </label>
       </div>
     
      
      </div>



   <!-- Right Panel-->
   <div id="right" class="container">
    <label>Email Id:</label>
    <input type="email"
                        name="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        ng-model="email" 
                        Placeholder="Enter Email Id" 
                        tabindex="2"
                        required>
                <span ng-show="homeForm.email.$touched && homeForm.email.$error.required"><div class="color">Enter Email Id</div></span><br>
              <div ng-switch="referance">
                    <label>Referance</label>
                        <select ng-model="referance" 
                                name="referance" 
                                class="form-control"
                                onChange="changeTextBox()"
                                id="referance"
                                tabindex="4"
                                required >
                            <option value="byReferance" >By Referance</option>
                            <option value="newsPaper" >News Paper</option>
                            <option value="email">Email</option>
                            <option value="socialMedia" >Social Media</option>
                        </select>
                        <span ng-show="homeForm.referance.$touched && homeForm.referance.$error.required">
                        <div class="color">Select Referance.</div>
                        </span>
                        <br>

                        <div ng-switch-when="byReferance">
                            <label>Referance Name</label>
                            <input type="text" 
                                    name="nameref" 
                                    id="nameref"  
                                    class="form-control"  
                                    ng-model="nameref" 
                                    Placeholder="Enter Name Of Referance"  
                                    tabindex="5"
                                    required
                                    >
                            <span ng-show="homeForm.nameref.$touched && homeForm.nameref.$error.required">
                                <div class="color">Enter Referance Name.</div>
                            </span>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div >
         <input onClick="return check()" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success"   value="Submit" ng-disabled="homeForm.$invalid">
         <input type="reset"  class="btn btn-default"   value="Reset">
        </div>
  </form>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Provide a plunkr.And it's $scope, not $scop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

load ngStorage.js after angular.js and not before

```
<script src="js/ngStorage-master/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js">
```

change this to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js">
<script src="js/ngStorage-master/ngStorage.js"></script>
```

also you have multiple instances of jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

remove that... same with angular, remove multiple versions of angular as well